# Do they still use tiger roars in the 2019 "Lion King" movie?

Tags: production, sound-effects, the-lion-king-2019

In the original *Lion King* movie, the lion's roars (or at least Mufasa's) was not actually a lion's roar; it was a combination of other sounds. From [the wikia](https://lionking.fandom.com/wiki/Mufasa#Trivia):

> The roar that Mufasa roars offscreen before saving Simba and Nala from the hyenas isn't actually a real lion's roar, but the combination of a grizzly's roar, a tiger's roar and F-16 Flyby[sic]<sup>1</sup> Falcon.

This was due to the fact that a lion's roar was not actually as "powerful" as they wanted it to be, in the original movie.

Is this still the case in the 2019 remake?

<sup>1</sup><sub>The actual name of the aircraft is the "Fighting Falcon".</sub>

Comment: IMO a real lion's "roar" sounds a bit like somebody puking.

Comment: They should have used the Williams scream

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's not a lion's roar for sure and the F-35 was involved. For detail take the word of God from the [*Hollywood Reporter*](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/behind-screen/lion-king-sound-team-recreating-stampede-iconic-roar-1225750):

> **Did you use other archival elements from the animated movie?**
>
> There's a moment where Simba roars and we think, "My God, how did he
>   make that sound?" and we come to discover it's Mufasa. And Jon said,
>   "In that scene, I think they used some things other than lion vocals
>   to get that intensity to the roar" and [supervising sound editor Frank
>   Eulner and I] said, "Okay, we better get those elements." They had
>   actually used an F-14 (aircraft) as a component and a number of other
>   things. So, I took that and I thought, "Okay cool, I can use that.
>   I'll put it in, but let me embellish it and see if we can make it even
>   cooler." And so **I used an F-35 and some other elements,** and that
>   roar became a big climatic moment that borrows from the original track
>   and also is kind of glorified by other elements as well, some of which
>   are not lion, and that's the only case where I did that. I was very
>   careful that we used lion recordings in every other moment of the
>   film.

Also from [MPAA](https://www.mpaa.org/2019/07/how-the-sound-team-helped-the-lion-king-roar/):

> Boyes says. “Jon wanted to reference the original film so the Mufasa roar you hear is the same but we included additional elements as it’s meant to be one of the strongest roars in the film.”

There are no specific words about using a tiger's roar but it suggests they did it same as the animated version with some addition.

Comment: They only wanted to "reference" the original film? How cute.

Comment: “climatic moment” or “climactic moment”, that’s the question…

Comment: @GreySage The new film references the original in the same way the new F-35 references the F-16, if you know what I mean.